# How to initiate a matrix with indexed parameters

Tags: matrix, parametric-functions, list-manipulation, scripting, parameters

I couldn't find it in the documentation, so I'm posting it here.
I want to create two by two matrices as follows:
$$
`W = \begin{bmatrix}w_{11} & w_{12} \\ w_{21} & w_{22} \end{bmatrix}, 
V = \begin{bmatrix}v_{11} & v_{21} \\ v_{12} & v_{22} \end{bmatrix}`
$$
so I could calculate $V^{-1}$ and see the result with the parameters $v_{ij}$'s.

Tnx.

Comment: mat = Array[v, {2, 2}] defines it and Inverse inverts it.

Comment: I'm receiving the error: `No Wolfram Language translation found.`.

Comment: Unsuccessfully, I've tried both on the web and desktop interpreters. Here is a link to my try in the online interface: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mat+%3D+Array%5Bv%2C+%7B2%2C+2%7D%5D

Comment: Questions solely about Wolfram|Alpha are not appropriate for this site. This site is for Q&A about Mathematica and the Wolfram Language.

Comment: In Wolfram|Alpha enter `inverse of {{v[1,1], v[1,2]}, {v[2,1], v[2,2]}}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Array takes a function, not  a variable.
2. Array elements can not have the same name as the array, this gives an infinite recursion.

   wmat= Array[Subscript[w,  #1, #2] &, {2, 2}]
   vmat= Array[Subscript[v,  #1, #2] &, {2, 2}]

[image]

And the inverse can be calculated by:

```
Inverse[vmat]
```

[image]